# Expression Encoder SDK in Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight-4.0, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk

We are trying to build a silverlight application that allows a user to stream video to a IIS smooth streaming server using the Encoder SDK. This application will stream video from a users desk to a TV screen at our front desk that is connected to a computer running another silverlight application.

When I try and add the encoder assemblies to the project I get:

You can't add a reference to Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Api2.dll as it was not built against the Silverlight runtime. Silverlight projects will only work with Silverlight assemblies.

Is there a way for me to kick off a encoder live session from a silverlight application? I've considered running a remote command and starting encoder from a command line but I'd like to use the Encoder OM if at all possible.

Thanks,

Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after more research I've found that it's not possible to do inside of a silverlight application. I have to use a local WCF Service to implement the encoder SDK and access the service from the silverlight app.

thanks,

Neil